# Running Django with sudo can't find installed homebrew packages

Tags: python, django, homebrew, sudo

I have a Django project that I want to run at port 80 with `manage.py runserver`. In my project I use the [Wand](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Wand) library and I have installed freetype and imagemagick using homebrew:

```
brew install freetype imagemagick
```

To run Django at port 80 `runserver` is required to be run with `sudo`, but when I run runserver with `sudo` it doesn't seem to find imagemagick:

```
$ sudo ~/.pyenv/versions/myproject/bin/python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80
Password:
Performing system checks...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x11068c840>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Oskar/.pyenv/versions/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wand/api.py", line 180, in <module>
    libraries = load_library()
  File "/Users/Oskar/.pyenv/versions/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wand/api.py", line 135, in load_library
    raise IOError('cannot find library; tried paths: ' + repr(tried_paths))
OSError: cannot find library; tried paths: []

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Oskar/.pyenv/versions/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Oskar/.pyenv/versions/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/Users/Oskar/.pyenv/versions/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 359, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/Users/Oskar/.pyenv/versions/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 346, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/Oskar/.pyenv/versions/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/Users/Oskar/.pyenv/versions/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 16, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/Users/Oskar/.pyenv/versions/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 26, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/Users/Oskar/.pyenv/versions/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 254, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/Users/Oskar/.pyenv/versions/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/Oskar/.pyenv/versions/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 405, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/Users/Oskar/.pyenv/versions/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/Oskar/.pyenv/versions/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 398, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/Users/Oskar/.pyenv/versions/3.6.0/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/Oskar/git/myproject/myproject/urls.py", line 12, in <module>
    from views import about, index, upload
  File "/Users/Oskar/git/myproject/views.py", line 7, in <module>
    from wand.image import Image
  File "/Users/Oskar/.pyenv/versions/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wand/image.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .api import MagickPixelPacket, libc, libmagick, library
  File "/Users/Oskar/.pyenv/versions/myproject/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wand/api.py", line 206, in <module>
    'Try to install:\n  ' + msg)
ImportError: MagickWand shared library not found.
You probably had not installed ImageMagick library.
Try to install:
  brew install freetype imagemagick
```

---

Imagemagick files in brew:

```
$ ls -l $(brew --prefix imagemagick)/lib
total 7904
drwxr-xr-x  4 Oskar admin     128 Nov 11 14:25 ImageMagick
-r--r--r--  1 Oskar admin  553388 Nov 15 18:20 libMagick++-7.Q16HDRI.3.dylib
-r--r--r--  1 Oskar admin  913560 Nov 11 14:25 libMagick++-7.Q16HDRI.a
lrwxr-xr-x  1 Oskar admin      29 Nov 11 14:25 libMagick++-7.Q16HDRI.dylib -> libMagick++-7.Q16HDRI.3.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x  1 Oskar admin    1272 Nov 15 18:20 libMagick++-7.Q16HDRI.la
-r--r--r--  1 Oskar admin 1608056 Nov 15 18:20 libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.4.dylib
-r--r--r--  1 Oskar admin 2321824 Nov 11 14:25 libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.a
lrwxr-xr-x  1 Oskar admin      31 Nov 11 14:25 libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.dylib -> libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.4.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x  1 Oskar admin    1144 Nov 15 18:20 libMagickCore-7.Q16HDRI.la
-r--r--r--  1 Oskar admin 1109812 Nov 15 18:20 libMagickWand-7.Q16HDRI.4.dylib
-r--r--r--  1 Oskar admin 1564192 Nov 11 14:25 libMagickWand-7.Q16HDRI.a
lrwxr-xr-x  1 Oskar admin      31 Nov 11 14:25 libMagickWand-7.Q16HDRI.dylib -> libMagickWand-7.Q16HDRI.4.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x  1 Oskar admin    1214 Nov 15 18:20 libMagickWand-7.Q16HDRI.la
drwxr-xr-x 10 Oskar admin     320 Nov 15 18:20 pkgconfig
```

---

All libMagickWand dylib files

```
$ sudo find / -name "libMagickWand*.dylib"
./usr/local/lib/libMagickWand-7.Q16HDRI.4.dylib
./usr/local/lib/libMagickWand-7.Q16HDRI.dylib
./usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick@6/6.9.9-9/lib/libMagickWand-6.Q16.dylib
./usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick@6/6.9.9-9/lib/libMagickWand-6.Q16.5.dylib
./usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick@6/6.9.9-11/lib/libMagickWand-6.Q16.dylib
./usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick@6/6.9.9-11/lib/libMagickWand-6.Q16.5.dylib
./usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick@6/6.9.9-20/lib/libMagickWand-6.Q16.dylib
./usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick@6/6.9.9-20/lib/libMagickWand-6.Q16.5.dylib
./usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick@6/6.9.9-21/lib/libMagickWand-6.Q16.dylib
./usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick@6/6.9.9-21/lib/libMagickWand-6.Q16.5.dylib
./usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick@6/6.9.9-19/lib/libMagickWand-6.Q16.dylib
./usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick@6/6.9.9-19/lib/libMagickWand-6.Q16.5.dylib
./usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick@6/6.9.9-10/lib/libMagickWand-6.Q16.dylib
./usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick@6/6.9.9-10/lib/libMagickWand-6.Q16.5.dylib
./usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick@6/6.9.9-17/lib/libMagickWand-6.Q16.dylib
./usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick@6/6.9.9-17/lib/libMagickWand-6.Q16.5.dylib
./usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick@6/6.9.9-12/lib/libMagickWand-6.Q16.dylib
./usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick@6/6.9.9-12/lib/libMagickWand-6.Q16.5.dylib
./usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick@6/6.9.9-15/lib/libMagickWand-6.Q16.dylib
./usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick@6/6.9.9-15/lib/libMagickWand-6.Q16.5.dylib
./usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick@6/6.9.9-23/lib/libMagickWand-6.Q16.dylib
./usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick@6/6.9.9-23/lib/libMagickWand-6.Q16.5.dylib
./usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick@6/6.9.9-14/lib/libMagickWand-6.Q16.dylib
./usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick@6/6.9.9-14/lib/libMagickWand-6.Q16.5.dylib
./usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.7-11/lib/libMagickWand-7.Q16HDRI.4.dylib
./usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.7-11/lib/libMagickWand-7.Q16HDRI.dylib
```

Running this without `sudo` on another port works as expected, how can I also make it work on port 80?

Comment: Yes, with homebrew without sudo

Comment: This is happening because of difference in environment variables between the two. Run `env` and `sudo env` and compare `PATH` variables between two. if the are same then compare rest variables and tell us the differences

Comment: @hoefling I've added the output to the question.

Comment: @TarunLalwani Both `env` and `sudo env` have the same for `PATH` variable

Comment: Updated question with list of libMagickWand dylib files

Comment: I have MAGICK_HOME set to `/usr/local/opt/imagemagick@6`

Comment: @hoefling We do? How should I use it? Deleting it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: @hoefling Perfect! It works now, thank you so much :)

Comment: Glad I could help :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Cleaning up different `imagemagick` installs

1. First of all, the [last version of `imagemagick` is currently not supported by `wand`](https://github.com/dahlia/wand/blob/master/wand/api.py#L58), so you can safely uninstall it if you don't use it to avoid interference with `imagemagick@6` that is necessary to fire up `wand`:

   ```
   $ brew uninstall imagemagick
   ```

   This is optional, though.

   If you want to leave both versions installed, I would still unlink `imagemagick` in favor of the old dylibs as `wand` works on my machine without setting the `MAGICK_PATH`:

   ```
   $ brew unlink imagemagick
   Unlinking /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.7-11... 72 symlinks removed
   ```
2. Link the `imagemagick@6`:

   ```
   $ brew link imagemagick@6
   Linking /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick@6/6.9.9-23... 76 symlinks created
   ```
3. Check if this will already suffice (as I said, this setup works on my machine already):

   ```
   $ sudo python3.6 -c "from wand.image import Image"
   ```

   If no error is raised, you are done! You can also clear the `MAGICK_PATH` variable as it is obsolete now.

#### If the points above did not help

You should leave `MAGICK_PATH` as it is because it's the key for `wand` to find the libraries. To propagate the var into sudo session, modify `sudo` settings:

```
$ sudo visudo
```

Add line `Defaults env_keep += "MAGICK_PATH"`, save and exit. You may need to start a new terminal session for changes to take effect. This will ensure that the `MAGICK_PATH` variable is passed to the `sudo` session.

Answer (score 0):

Propagate relevant parts of your environment into root's environment:

```
$ sudo env PATH=$PATH PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH ~/.pyenv/versions/myproject/bin/python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80
```